how to get the path of the open folder in vscode api?
The workspaceFolders variable of the workspace namespace works when the extension is running in a workspace.
Is there a method to identify the current open folder that was not open as a workspace?
If I simply open a folder this variable is undefined and I can't get the current folder path.

How are you opening that folder?  Are you still in the Extension Host for testing?

Could you please elaborate more, I did not understand the question. I am kinda new to this.

According to the documentation, you will have a workspace even if you simply open a folder (either by running code . in the terminal or using the File > Open Folder menu). See this and this section for details.
When your workspace is open, both workspace.workspaceFolders[0] and the deprecated workspace.rootPath should contain the folder path.
(There are some cases when you have no workspaces at all so the above will be undefined; see the note section in the first paragraph of the documentation. But if you open a folder as you write in your question, this does not apply).
